# Is repeating an oath for each day permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, oaths

Can I make this oath? For example, I made an oath to not make this certain sin for tomorrow and I made this oath like this everyday.

Comment: You are asking a question in the internet on a question and answer site not a fatwa site so what do you expect? Anybody could answer here to the best of their knowledge, as you have the "informed" badge you should know this! As a matter of fact your question doesn't need deep studies of Astrophysics nor rocket science nor more than a good knowledge of Islam and qur'an to be answered and you could even figure out your answer yourself by a little effort and common sense. Please use meaningful question titles, help me or please answer me doesn't reveal anything about what you want to ask!

Comment: Jazakallah khayran bro.Maybe my questions hurt you.Im very sorry.Im just afraid that my question were anwered by laymen.Im very sorry.So,is making that oath haram or not?I have search fatwa on google but its not there.May Allah reward you bro and Im deeply sorry.

Answer (score 3):

An oath is, an oath, is an oath... it must be regarded and respected as such and not become something worthless. Especially if it was made as a vow to Allah and not a simple promise.

Allah informed us about it and the corresponding rulings saying:

> Allah will not impose blame upon you for what is meaningless in your oaths, but He will impose blame upon you for [breaking] what you intended of oaths. So its expiation is the feeding of ten needy people from the average of that which you feed your [own] families or clothing them or the freeing of a slave. But whoever cannot find [or afford it] - then a fast of three days [is required]. That is the expiation for oaths when you have sworn. But guard your oaths. Thus does Allah make clear to you His verses that you may be grateful.
> ([5:89](https://legacy.quran.com/5/89))

It basically is not prohibited to repeat it everyday if this repetition has a certain -acceptable- goal (for example helping you to swear the oath and fulfill it or helping you not to fall into a sin).

However it is not recommended to reach a state in which an oath to Allah becomes meaningless, by breaking or disregarding it or acting against what one has promised  Allah. An oath shouldn't therefore become a habit.

As Allah informed us:

- > And do not make [your oath by] Allah an excuse against being righteous and fearing Allah and making peace among people. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing.
  > ([2:224](https://legacy.quran.com/2/224))
- > And do not obey every worthless habitual swearer ([68:10](https://legacy.quran.com/68/10))

Therefore an oath to Allah is a serious matter and shouldn't be taken with levity and easily. It could be fine to start your inner "fight" against falling into a sin by making this oath repetitively, but shouldn't reach the state of being a habit.
It certainly is not a good attribute of a person to be known as a repetitive swearer especially if this is connected by breaking oaths.

Comment: Alhamdhullilah!

Comment: Jazakallah khayran all of you. May Allah reward all of you with goodness and once again, Im very sorry for my question that may be hurt you.

Comment: I made an oath if I made  this certain sin(not goona tell you the sin)tomorrow I will fast for week and tonorrow again I made the same oath everyday.

Comment: Insha Allah by hilmy